# Authentication Vuex+Axios wrong url request status 404

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm trying to authenticate with an API that I'm using , but when I tried to login I receive this response:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) [http://localhost:8080/localhost:5000/api/login]"

I think the problem is with axios, because it is using my local Vue aplication adress+apiAdress to do the request.

main.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.use(axios)
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_API; //(http://localhost:5000/api
```

modules/auth.js:

```
import { AUTH_REQUEST, AUTH_ERROR, AUTH_SUCCESS, AUTH_LOGOUT } from '../actions/auth'
import { USER_REQUEST } from '../actions/user'
import axios from 'axios'

const state = { token: localStorage.getItem('user-token') || '', status: '', hasLoadedOnce: false }

const getters = {
  isAuthenticated: state => !!state.token,
  authStatus: state => state.status,
}

const actions = {
  [AUTH_REQUEST]: ({commit, dispatch}, user) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     commit(AUTH_REQUEST)
  axios({url: '/login', data: user, method: 'POST'})
  .then(resp => {
    localStorage.setItem('user-token', resp.token)
    // Here set the header of your ajax library to the token value.
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = resp.token
    commit(AUTH_SUCCESS, resp)
    dispatch(USER_REQUEST)
    resolve(resp)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    commit(AUTH_ERROR, err)
    localStorage.removeItem('user-token')
    reject(err)
  })
})
},
}

const mutations = {
  [AUTH_REQUEST]: (state) => {
  state.status = 'loading'
  },
  [AUTH_SUCCESS]: (state, resp) => {
    state.status = 'success'
    state.token = resp.token
    state.hasLoadedOnce = true
  },
  [AUTH_ERROR]: (state) => {
  state.status = 'error'
  state.hasLoadedOnce = true
  },
  [AUTH_LOGOUT]: (state) => {
    state.token = ''
  }
}

export default {
 state,
 getters,
 actions,
 mutations,
}
```

Login.vue:

```
  methods: {
    login() {
      const { username, password } = this
      this.$store.dispatch(AUTH_REQUEST, { username, password }).then(() => {
      this.$router.push('/')
   })
    },
```

Comment: Why u don't use full path of api? Try this: axios({url: 'http://localhost:5000/api', data: user, method: 'POST'})

Comment: can't use the full url if you have a different api endpoint for dev vs test vs prod

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define axios in main at all.

Also, axios is not a vue plugin, so `Vue.use(axios)` does nothing.

in your auth.js you can create an instance

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API
});
```

and in your actions, use the axios instance instead of axios

```js
const actions = {
  [AUTH_REQUEST]: ({commit, dispatch}, user) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     commit(AUTH_REQUEST)
  axiosInstance({url: '/login', data: user, method: 'POST'})
  .then(resp => {
    localStorage.setItem('user-token', resp.token)
    // Here set the header of your ajax library to the token value.
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = resp.token
    commit(AUTH_SUCCESS, resp)
    dispatch(USER_REQUEST)
    resolve(resp)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    commit(AUTH_ERROR, err)
    localStorage.removeItem('user-token')
    reject(err)
  })
})
```

This may however cause issues with updating your headers after the instance is created, so you may need to use some clever ways to get around that.

one way is to use a function, instead of a value, that way whenever you make a call, it uses the data in your local-storage

```js
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API,
  headers: {
    Authorization: {
      toString () {
        return `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token')}`
      }
    }
  }
})
```

another way is to create a new request every time you make a call

```js
const actions = {
  [AUTH_REQUEST]: ({ commit, dispatch }, user) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const axiosInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API
      });
      commit(AUTH_REQUEST)
      axiosInstance({
          url: '/login',
          data: user,
          method: 'POST'
        })
        .then(resp => {
          localStorage.setItem('user-token', resp.token)
          // Here set the header of your ajax library to the token value.
          axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = resp.token
          commit(AUTH_SUCCESS, resp)
          dispatch(USER_REQUEST)
          resolve(resp)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          commit(AUTH_ERROR, err)
          localStorage.removeItem('user-token')
          reject(err)
        })
    })
  },
  [SECURE_REQUEST]: ({ commit, dispatch }, user) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const axiosInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('user-token')
        }
      });
      commit(SECURE_REQUEST)
      axiosInstance({
          url: '/getData',
          data: user,
          method: 'POST'
        })
        // ...
    })
  },
}
```

another option (which is what I use these days) is using the `devServer.proxy` config. This requires though that you use Vue-Cli-3. It also assumes that the final static bundle will run on the same server as your API, which may not work for you.

also, check out this solution: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1383#issuecomment-405900504